# How to pause ExoPlayer 2 playback and resume (PlayerControl was removed)

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

In `ExoPlayer < 2.x` there was a class `PlayerControl` with `pause()` and `resume()` functions but it was removed. I can't find a way to do this on `ExoPlayer 2`.

How can I pause and resume a playback?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use `void setPlayWhenReady(boolean playWhenReady)`.
If Exo is ready, passing `false` will pause the player. Passing `true` will resume it. You can check the player's state using `getPlaybackState()`.

Comment: Kindly Answer with code so one can understand it correctly

Comment: To pause and play with the same button You can use : `player.setPlayWhenReady(!player.getPlayWhenReady());` .

Answer (score 44):

This is my way. Create two methods and call them when needed.

```
private void pausePlayer(){
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    player.getPlaybackState();
}
private void startPlayer(){
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    player.getPlaybackState();
}
```

call them here

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
   pausePlayer();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startPlayer();
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `player.getPlaybackState();` after the "play when ready" changed?

Comment: Exoplayer take `1sec/2sec` on resume `@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startPlayer();
}` how can i solve this audio plays but videos start late

Comment: @Caipivara It's not needed. Maybe he wanted to show it's possible to use it.

Answer (score 5):

play

`player.setPlayWhenReady(true);`

pause

`player.setPlayWhenReady(false);`

And you can check play state like this:

```
private boolean isPlaying() {
return player != null
    && player.getPlaybackState() != Player.STATE_ENDED
    && player.getPlaybackState() != Player.STATE_IDLE
    && player.getPlayWhenReady();
}
```

These codes are from `PlayerControlView`.

Comment: Why not simply `player.getPlaybackState()== Player.STATE_READY`